# How to implement a UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight to a UIScrollView using Objective C in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I'm working on multiple applications for my school. I just need this last bit of code and I was wondering how I could implement a UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight into the app for each textfield. What this does is it makes the textfield pop above the keyboard, rather than over lapping it. I have already implemented a UIScrollView, so if someone on here could be pretty descriptive, or post a link to a video, that would be well appreciated. I am new to coding. Thanks very much!!!!

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail.  Specifically, what is the issue you are trying to overcome?  Is it that a text field is hidden when the keyboard pops up?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750058/iphone-keyboard-blocks-screen) It worked for me.